# Prior art request: RE38782

Tags: prior-art-request

[USRE38782](http://www.google.com/patents/USRE38782)

The patent covers a blanket with fabric loops sewn on the edges, as shown in the following image:

[image: Image of patented blanket]

The commercial product is called "[Taggies](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00C2SEFEK)".

Priority date is late 1999. Seems like there's likely some good prior-art, given the simple design and the late priority date.

Answer (score 2):

For a prior art search, you could check out "baby blank" utility or design with a priority date before Dec 2, 1999. Look for ones that are lapsed or have priority date > 20 years old. Interestingly, the TAGGIES utility patent lapsed for non-payment in 2014. https://www.google.com/patents/US6427265

One problem is, once you find prior art, the cost to invalidate the design patent will be **enormous**. 
It will be more cost effective to design around the patent. The design patent specifically refers to colorful LOOPS. If you make a colorful non-loop on a blanket, you should be fine. The "non-loop" could be a knot, a fringe, a tag, lace, braid etc.